Alternative to connection.setAutoCommit(false) since it doesn't work for JdbcTemplate
I am going through some tutorials that says to start transaction you have to write
connection.setAutoCommit(false)
But it seems that this is ignored by JdbcTemplate that I am using to actually insert records.
Can some share a Transaction code that works with JdbcTemplate but that doesn't include @Transactional because my goal is to try to simulate @Transactional to better understand what it does.
So in the below Code I get connection from jdbcTeamplate and use it to start Transaction but it is ignored when inserting Records with jdbcTeamplate inside Repository.
PersonService.java
@Service
public class PersonService {

  //PROPERTIES
  @Autowired private PersonRepository personRepository;
  @Autowired private JdbcTemplate     jdbcTemplate;

  //=========================================================================================================
  // INSERT RECORDS
  //=========================================================================================================
  public void insertRecords() throws SQLException {

    //GET DB CONNECTION
    Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

    //FIRST RECORD IS ALWAYS INSERTED (It is outside the Transaction)
    Person person0 = new Person(0, "Person Outside Transaction", 100);
    personRepository.save(person0);

    //TRANSACTION
    try { //It doesn't work with try(connection) => throws java.sql.SQLRecoverableException

      //START TRANSACTION
      connection.setAutoCommit(false);

      //EXECUTE SQL STATEMENTS
      for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        if(i==2) { throw new Exception("Exception"); }
        Person person = new Person(0, "Person " + i, 10 * i);
        personRepository.save(person);
      }

      //COMMIT TRANSACTION
      connection.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      //ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      connection.rollback();   //throws java.sql.SQLRecoverableException
    }
    finally {
      connection.close();
    }

  }

}

PersonRepository.java
@Repository
public class PersonRepository {

  //PROPERTIES
  @Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  //=========================================================================================================
  // INSERT
  //=========================================================================================================
  public void save(Person person) throws SQLException {
    jdbcTemplate.update(
      " INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME, AGE) VALUES(?, ?)"
      , new Object[] { person.getName(), person.getAge() }
    );
  }

}


I don't think this is something that can be done in the way that you want.
if you look at how the JdbcTemplate works, the update eventually lands in to the execute method which obtains the database connection using the DataSourceUtils - which uses the TransactionSynchronizationManager. Check it out yourself here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/775a23b39d6332c7e85a840e3452b6d86d0ad5c0/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L1161
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/775a23b39d6332c7e85a840e3452b6d86d0ad5c0/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.java#L106C51-L106C84
If you really want to understand what @Transactional is doing - you can dig into the github and follow it. Maybe setup breakpoints and step through it. My suggestion would be to read some tutorials and trust that the framework is doing what it claims.

So far I was able to make it work like this. But it doesn't look too good. Any other solutions?
PersonRepository2.java
@Repository
public class PersonRepository2 {

  //=========================================================================================================
  // INSERT
  //=========================================================================================================
  public void save(Connection connection, Person person) throws SQLException {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, true));

    jdbcTemplate.update(
      " INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME, AGE) VALUES(?, ?)"
      , new Object[] { person.getName(), person.getAge() }
    );

  }

}


I was also able to make it work with changes in DatabaseConfig by returning SingleConnectionDataSource but this now means that I am not using Connection Pool?
DatabaseConfig.java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    //@Bean
    //public DataSource dataSource() {
    //    return new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/orcl", "TEST", "LETMEIN");
    //}

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
      SingleConnectionDataSource  dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
                                  dataSource.setUrl     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/orcl");
                                  dataSource.setUsername("TEST");
                                  dataSource.setPassword("LETMEIN");
                                //dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

}


Or create this SingleConnectionDataSource inside Service.java and then give it to Repository.
OK but basically all three solutions are acctually just one solution by using SingleConnectionDataSource. And therefore no Connection Pool which I beleive is what is being used by default by JdbcTemplate.
PersonService3.java
@Service
public class PersonService3 {

  //PROPERTIES
  @Autowired private PersonRepository3 personRepository;
  @Autowired private DataSource        dataSource;

  //=========================================================================================================
  // INSERT RECORDS
  //=========================================================================================================
  public void insertRecords() throws SQLException {

    //GET DB CONNECTION
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    //WE ARE CREATING IT BY PROVIDING THE SAME CONNECTION
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, true));

    //FIRST RECORD IS ALWAYS INSERTED (It is outside the Transaction)
    Person person0 = new Person(0, "Person Outside Transaction", 100);
    personRepository.save(jdbcTemplate, person0);


You are mixing a lot of things here, that's why it's not clear why it does not work and what happens.
First of all, if you want to try such low-level stuff, try to avoid using the Spring-created Repository. It has a lot of things happening internally and they will confuse you. E.g., if you take a look at Spring's SimpleJpaRepository, you'll see it uses @Transactional.
To execute an insert, you can use a PreparedStatement.
Whether you use a single connection or connection pool does not play a role here.
